# Android Honeycomb advanced "Table"/Grid control

Tags: android, user-controls

I am new to Android and I am researching developing a Tablet only application for my company.  I was investigating this and I am wondering what developers are using for a "Grid" control (not the grid layout) with support for things like horizontal/vertical scrolling, event driven row/column clicks, features like Column Lockings, render as image, etc.

TableLayout/TableRow at first glance doesn't "seem" sophisticated enough.  Are there third party control vendors (a la ComponentOne) which offer Grid components?  What are other Android developers using?

Thanks

Comment: You need to build a custom view component.